# Naturally flowing images with text over them

Tags: css

I have an HTML file with some images:

```
<img src="image1.jpg">
<img src="image2.jpg">
<img src="image3.jpg">
...
<img src="imageN.jpg">
```

They indeed naturally flow from the 1st row to the 2nd etc. and are automatically reflowed by browser when the width of viewport (window) is changed:
[image]
[image]

I'm satisfied with this behavior, and all what I want is to *put a text over every image* — as in the picture above.

I tried different CSS tricks as involving flexbox or relative / absolute positioning, but always there were some bugs: not natural flow, the text out of the image after changing the viewport's width, and so on.

Is there a way how to reach my goal — preferably *without* JavaScript, only with CSS?

Comment: Try or search for flex box [short Intro](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). I think you will do it yourshelf.

Comment: You can't use positioning to align text over **individual** images in that fashion. The position has to be related to the *image* not the image or text container. You will need JS.

Comment: @9841pratik, that intro is very good, I read it some years ago, but nice from you for trying help me. (As I wrote in my question, flexbox didn't help me.)

Comment: @Paulie_D, it seems (sadly) that you are right.

Comment: If we knew more about the use case it might be possble to offer suggestions but I can't think of a reason to do what it is you are trying to do. If the text relates to an image a standard image overlay would work. I don't see a need to have *all* the text in a different wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the pseudo-element `::before` and add a data attribute that contains the text that is over the image. In that way, you can manipulate the data attribute through javascript if you want to build something dynamic.

```css
.gallery {  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  
  color: #fff;
}

.gallery > .image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.gallery > .image-container::before {
  content: attr(data-figcapture);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.gallery > .image-container > img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div data-figcapture="image 1" class="image-container">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div data-figcapture="image 2" class="image-container">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div data-figcapture="image 3" class="image-container">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div data-figcapture="image 4" class="image-container">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div data-figcapture="image 5" class="image-container">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just do it simply with flex box! The trick is making text absolute positioned, so that it can be at the top of the image, and using flexbox as the container of both the image and the text.

Here is a quick demo:

**UPDATED HTML SEMANTIC**

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  max-width: 100vw;
}

.image{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

figcaption{
  position: absolute;
  color: hsla(226, 33%, 32%, 1);
  font-weight: bold;

}

.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 300px);
  grid-auto-rows: 300px;
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;

  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <figure class="image">
    <img src="https://www.mortenhansen.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/quiz-intro-image-2000x1720.png" alt="">
    <figcaption>Work Hard</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="image">
    <img src="https://www.mortenhansen.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/quiz-intro-image-2000x1720.png" alt="">
    <figcaption>Work Hard</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="image">
    <img src="https://www.mortenhansen.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/quiz-intro-image-2000x1720.png" alt="">
    <figcaption>Work Hard</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="image">
    <img src="https://www.mortenhansen.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/quiz-intro-image-2000x1720.png" alt="">
    <figcaption>Work Hard</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="image">
    <img src="https://www.mortenhansen.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/quiz-intro-image-2000x1720.png" alt="">
    <figcaption>Work Hard</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="image">
    <img src="https://www.mortenhansen.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/quiz-intro-image-2000x1720.png" alt="">
    <figcaption>Work Hard</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="image">
    <img src="https://www.mortenhansen.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/quiz-intro-image-2000x1720.png" alt="">
    <figcaption>Work Hard</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="image">
    <img src="https://www.mortenhansen.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/quiz-intro-image-2000x1720.png" alt="">
    <figcaption>Work Hard</figcaption>
  </figure>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand why someone voted down such a perfect answer.

Comment: Thanks for your nice solution. BTW you misspell the word **“both”** — you incorrectly wrote *“bouth”*, both in your answer and in your profile. (In your profile there is another small mistake — “**a** happy guy” is the right form.)

Comment: Instead of <div> and <h2>, this would be a much better answer if it used <figure> and <figcaption>.

Comment: @MarianD no problem, we are here to help (and thank for you for the tip!).

Comment: @RayButterworth you are absolutely right, using <figure> and <figcaption> is a way better semantic than the tags I used in the example.

Comment: Please, look at the other up-voted answer from Rickard Elimää, it's nice, too.

Comment: @Pedro, I decided to change the accepted answer from your one to Rickard Elimää's. As it's not possible to accept 2 answers and I don't want to lower your reputation (because your answer was the first one and is very nice, too), I browsed your other answers and voted up some valuable ones.